# Install R package from github without devtools (due to firewall)

Tags: r, twitter, github, r-package

I am not able to use devtools to install R packages from github since I have a firewall that prevents R from connecting to the internet.

I thought of making a .tar.gz file from the git repository but the problem is that the repository does not contain an MD5 file and I am afraid that the installation will fail without it.

How do I go about installing the package?

(in case it matters, the package is AnomalyDetection)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a md5 file. You can create the .tar.gz on another machine and import it.

This may of course still violate your company's (somewhat obnoxious) security protocol because the *intent* of the block presumably is to prevent you from installing third-party software in the first place.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work. I get this error: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
  cannot open compressed file 'AnomalyDetection/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

Comment: Well is the file there or not?  We talked about a tarball, now you try to access individual files from it.  The command you may want is `install.packages()`.

Comment: R in windows has an option to install a package from a local zip file. I made a zip file and selected the option and it failed and produced the error above

Comment: The zip file is prepared by prior `R CMD INSTALL` on another machine; you only have sources so you still want a source install. Maybe check with the R Installation and Administration manual that come with your copy of R.